# Google Chrome Application Mode: Possible to isolate multiple instances?

Tags: google-chrome, mode, isolation

I want to run multiple Google Chrome application windows logged into the same web site (Twitter.com, say), each with different credentials. Is this possible? If so, how?

My initial testing shows that multiple Chrome app windows are not sufficiently isolated to do this. Logging into the second account logs me into the second account in both windows, suggesting that they are sharing information just as two Chrome tabs might.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Chrome "Incognito" window for this.

As you've found, Chrome windows are (like in most browsers) just groupings for tabs, not an authentication barrier.

Comment: I hoped that would do the trick, but it doesn't. Within minutes, Twitter window A starts behaving as though it is logged into Twitter account B. Both were started in separate incognito windows.

Comment: Right, you get 2 logins: one for normal windows, and one for Incognito windows.  "Incognito" mode uses separate auth, but windows still do not.

Comment: Gotcha. So I could potentially sign in twice (once normal, once incognito), but not three times.

Answer (score 1):

look for a plugin called "swap my cookies"

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with chrome Incognito windows.
Take a look here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24690.
So that's right you can create only two isolated session: one incognito and one normal.

See the latest post:

> Although it's an extension / plug-in and not in core Chromium, MultiLogin has been working quite well for me: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nccllfnllopfpcbjdgjdlfmomnfgnnbk
>
> It can open new tabs, each with their own cookie jar.